# PVC in pending state

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to provision PV with RBD using https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.7/examples/persistent-volume-provisioning/rbd

But I have faced an issue when my PVC is in Pending state without any meaningful log

```
root@ubuntu:~# kubectl describe pvc
Name:          claim1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  fast
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner=kubernetes.io/rbd
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
Events:        <none>
```

Comment: Encountering the same issue with RBD. What did you have to change to get past this?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you don't have volume defined in your pvc :

[image: missing_volume]

I got the problem also if the volumeName is not correct or if it doesn't exist. Indeed, there are no logs or events that show the problem.

If all is working fine, the status should be :

```
Status:        Bound
```

Comment: After spending hours of time finally this answer helped me to resolve the issue